# SQL Developer will not start on Windows 8.1

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, windows-8.1

I have been trying to install Oracle SQL Developer on my 64bit Windows 8.1 machine. I have tried to install it with the embedded jdk and without the jdk.  when I remove Java and I start SQL Developer it comes up and asks for the location of Java, I then tell it where it is. In either situation when starting SQL Developer it come up and starts to install for about 10 seconds, the progress bar says loading and the SQL Developer screen goes away with no errors and no explaniation. I have been trying this for days. I have removed and redownloaded all files and I get the same result.

Please if anyone can help I would be grateful. I need this for my course and I am unable to get anything completed.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I've run into many problems with the 64-bit version of the JDK.  I would try downloading the SQL Developer with embedded 32-bit version of the JDK instead.

Comment: I'm not a SQL Developer installation expert but I think you should mention exactly what version you have.

Comment: start the  bin/sqldeveloper.exe this will show a console with logs of what's going on. Add that to this and we can help more.

Comment: hi, I am tying to install SQL 18.1 with JDK 8,  I just removed all instance and restarted computer and I am getting the same result. when starting it comes up will not go past the loading and then closes with no errors or any kind of explaniation. I have looked for a bin sql developer and am I am not seeing it however I did find sql developer/bin and found the following the log:

Comment: .level=SEVERE

# Set the default logging level for the root logger
#oracle.level = INFO

# --- ConsoleHandler ---
# Override of global logging level
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
oracle.dbtools.logging.LogPaneHandler.level=ALL
oracle.ide.log.QueuedLoggingHandler.level=OFF

Comment: @MirandaLynn try this please. Navigate to the sqldeveloper/bin directory in a CMD window. Run the sqldeveloper.exe there. When it 'craps out' on startup, it should write some error messages back to the CMD window

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I created an account with Oracle, accept the Terms and licences agreement. Search for the version you are trying to install and make sure it is the right one for the OS, 32 OR 64 bits with JDK 8. After extracting the files make sure you run as Admin, your SQL will complete installing. When you are installing they go into a default folder in C-drive or you can choose the path. Hope it helps.